# Nginx while serving lots of static files Aborted

Tags: performance, http, nginx

While loading a lot of tiny/regular images on my Nginx server since yesterday I start getting very slow times for certain images (in random order)

I've setup the sendfile_max_chunk 128k; directive to try and mitigate the issue but still no success.

Server loads at lightning speed but some static files get Aborted and endup loading after 30s or more.
[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezIW7.png)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;TR;** You need to cache frequently requested files, allow to request multiple files in terms of one HTTP session (`keepalive`), and use caching for SSL sessions to avoid delays in SSL handshake.

1. Use [`open_file_cache`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#open_file_cache)
2. As you actively use SSL, please consider to use [`ssl_session_cache`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache), [`keepalive`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive), [`keepalive_timeout`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout) [`keepalive_requests`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_requests), use [`http2` module if available](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html)
3. Read official [nginx tuning article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/)

`open_file_cache` example:

```
open_file_cache          max=2048 inactive=12h;
open_file_cache_valid    12h;
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors   off;
```

`ssl_session_cache` example:

```
ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:32m;
ssl_session_timeout 4h;
ssl_buffer_size     1400;
```

`http2` example for "default" server block, for more info [read DO article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-with-http-2-support-on-ubuntu-16-04):

```
server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl http2 deferred reuseport;
  listen [::]:443 default_server ssl http2 deferred reuseport ipv6only=on;
  server_name _;
}
```